# Question on Highcharts SVG element create / destroy using Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I've read various examples on how to use the `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` to create custom SVG text etc.
However, I'm wondering what is the correct practices to create and clean them up?

Currently I make them at the `events.redraw` hook (because I want to update the SVG text based on the dynamic data), however it looks like the `redraw` hook is being called at various occasions multiple times (it looks like it'd redraw on add series and data being added) and then the SVG does not get cleaned up... so I ended up having multiple copies of the same SVG elements in the chart. Any subsequence redraw would obviously keep adding more SVGElements into the chart.

Questions:

- Do i need to keep track of all the generated SVGElements myself and call destroy() manually every time I redraw them?
- Is there any internal trackers in Highcharts that tracks the created SVG using `SVGRenderer`? (so that I could maybe use the internal ref to call destroy myself)
- If I am not supposed to draw them in redraw event, what is the recommended hook to draw my SVG elements where I need dynamic update on those generated SVG elements.
- Do I absolutely need to keep track of my own references on the SVG elements? Seems a bit too much of the overhead/hassle to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you need to keep track of all the generated SVG elements, which you want to update, but better than destroying them is to update their attributes.
2. No, there is no such trackers.
3. You can draw the elements in the `load` event and redraw them when you need to (for example when you change your data).
4. No, you have to keep track only those elements that you need update. Maybe some of your problems will be resolved by by annotations?  https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module

---

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    var chart = this,
      series = chart.series[0],
      x = series.points[2].plotX,
      y = series.points[2].plotY - 50;

    if (!chart.customElement) {
      chart.customElement = chart.renderer.text().add();
    }

    chart.customElement.attr({
      text: 'some text ' + Math.random(),
      x,
      y
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t250crx1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr